# Как добавить закладки в pdf

Tags: c#, html, pdf

Есть интересная библиотека HiqPdf для конвертирования HTML в PDF. Есть несколько html файлов и я без проблем могу сконвертировать их в один общий PDF. Каким образом можно добавить закладки в общий pdf для каждого сконвертированного html? т.е. было сконвертировано 2 html - соответственно 2 закладки с их названием. Вот пример кода, с помощью которого я пытаюсь это сделать. Не пойму, где ошибка моя.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create an empty PDF document
        PdfDocument singlePdf = new PdfDocument();

        HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();
        htmlToPdfConverter.Document.Outlines.OutlineHeadingTags = true;
        htmlToPdfConverter.Document.Viewer.PageMode = PdfPageMode.Outlines;

        string[] urls = new[] {"http://www.hiqpdf.com", "http://www.cnn.com"};
        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            byte[] pdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrlToMemory(url);
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(pdfBuffer);
            PdfDocument pdf = PdfDocument.FromStream(stream);
            singlePdf.AddDocument(pdf);
        }

        singlePdf.WriteToFile(@"c:\temp\singlePdf.pdf");
        singlePdf.Close();
    }
```

Comment: [оно](http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/AutoOutlinesAndLinks.aspx)? Вообще это коммерческая библиотека с поддержкой и документацией, стоит в первую очередь обращаться туда.

Comment: Да, это оно. Я брал несколько html файлов и пробовал сконвертировать - все конвертируется, но закладок нет

Comment: На странице по ссылке можно посмотреть код генерации оглавления. Автоматом там ничего не происходит, нужны явные указания.

Comment: я отредактировал вопрос и добавил пример кода, чтобы, наверное, было более понятнее с моей стороны что есть и что не получается

Comment: В общем, разобрался. Есть два вариант - 1. автоматом, но получается не тот вариант. 2. есть способ добавления закладки с ссылкой на страницу.